# python-logstash not working

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have an elasticsearch cluster (ELK) and some nodes sending logs to the logstash using filebeat.
Lately I added a new application server, who is sending logs to my logstash using `python-logstash`.

My logstash input configuration looks something like this :

```
input {
   beats {
     type => beats
     port => 5044
   }
   udp {
     port => 5044
   }
}
```

My application server sends the logs successfully to the logstash. On my logstash machine I tried to run the following command:

```
tcpdump -nn | grep x.x.x.x
```

`x.x.x.x` is the ip of my application server.

My code is :

```
self.logger=logging.getLogger(logger_name)
self.logger.addHandler(logstash.UDPLogstashHandler(ELASTICSEARCH_LOGSTASH_SERVER, 5044, version=1, message_type='bla',fqdn=elastic_fqdn))
```

elastic_fqdn is the hostname of the hosted server.

I was able to see the packets, they looked fine (`udp`, port 5044), but I couldn't see any document in my kibana/elasticsearch.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Does _anything_ happen with the incoming packets? You should probably take a look at this issue to see how to set the debug flag: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1959

Comment: Could you try without the `version=1` argument?

Comment: I have the same issue. If I do <code>echo "anything" | nc logstashhost 5044</code> from my app server, it goes through like it should but no log messages are going through with or without version=1