# python-logstash and python-logstash-async not working with django

Tags: python, django, logstash

I tried two libraries to send some logs from our Django backend to our logging server:

- python-logstash
- python-logstash-async

Here are the things I also tried/verified:

- Verify the Ec2 security group is accepting on port tcp/5000 (logstash)
- Monitor traffic from local machine and logging server to verify any network traffic. Using `nc`  I was able to verify test logs being send and receive to our logging server.
- Re-create a bare minimum django project to see if there is an issue from versioning

I'm sending logs after running the `manage.py runserver`

```
class AppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app'
    
    def ready(self):
        logger.info('info local django logging ')
        logger.error('debug local django logging ')
        logger.debug('debug local django logging ')
        print('logging init')
```

This are the similar links that I've already checked:

- [python-logstash not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658857/python-logstash-not-working)?
- [How to use python-logstash on Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159088/how-to-use-python-logstash-on-django)

settings.py (python-logstash-async)

```
LOGGING = {
  'formatters': {
      'logstash': {
          '()': 'logstash_async.formatter.DjangoLogstashFormatter',
          'message_type': 'python-logstash',
          'fqdn': False, # Fully qualified domain name. Default value: false.
          'extra_prefix': 'dev', #
          'extra': {
              'environment': 'local'
          }
      },
  },
  'handlers': {
      'logstash': {
          'level': 'DEBUG',
          'class': 'logstash_async.handler.AsynchronousLogstashHandler',
          'transport': 'logstash_async.transport.TcpTransport',
          'host': 'my.remote.host', 
          'port': 5000,
          'ssl_enable': False,
          'ssl_verify': False,
          'database_path': 'memory',
      },
  },
  'loggers': {
      'django.request': {
          'handlers': ['logstash'],
          'level': 'DEBUG',
          'propagate': True,
      },
  },
}
```

Logstash conf:

```
input {
stdin {}
    tcp {
        port => 5000
        codec => json
    }
    gelf {
        type => docker
        port => 12201
    }

}

## Add your filters / logstash plugins configuration here

output {
stdout {}
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
        }
}
```

Details:

- Python Version: 3.7.2
- Django version: 2.1.3

Re-created django project:

- Python Version: 3.7.9
- Django Version: 3.1.5

So there is no outgoing traffic on my machine and there is not incoming traffic from our logging server, But I cant figure out why.

Any hint/idea would be helpful thanks!

Comment: I've met the same problem, did you solve the problem? =)

Comment: @AlbertBadretdinov, not yet unfortunately. I haven't able to revisit the problem

Comment: For future readers: We move on using filebeats, https://www.elastic.co/beats/filebeat.